# Bootstrap poor performance - custom-select resp select.form-control freezes for couple of seconds

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, performance, chromium

I use bootstrap 4.6 and I have a custom select with 10-20 options

```
 <select class="custom-select">
     <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
     <option value="1">a</option>
     ...
 </select>
```

See demo: https://codepen.io/Lieroo/project/editor/XwPeNz#

When I open and close the select, the browser freezes for couple of seconds.

[image: screenrecording]

1. When I remove 'custom-select' selector, it wont freeze.
2. It freezes only when there is a data table that uses display: grid on the page, although the custom-select is outside the grid's element.

The performance recording in chromium edge shows

What's going on? it is a bug in chromium, or on bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: No issues for me when recorded for 18 seconds: https://nimb.ws/B6xfDI

Comment: Interesting. I've attached screen recording to make sure you are doing the same as me. What OS/Browser/Version are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 / Chrome 89.0.4389.82.

Comment: Hmm, same here. I have 4k display with 150% zoom in Windows Display settings.  Can you verify, that you are doing exactly the same steps as me in the attached gif?

Comment: Check this: https://imgur.com/a/MTwNofu

Comment: We have had some customers report a similar problem, but can't reproduce ourselves. Did you by chance determine the cause of the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a windows / chromium bug related to accesibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chromium based browsers on Windows related to Accessibility.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1187638

It will be fixed in Chrome 90+;

Until then you can run your chromium browser with `-disable-renderer-accessibility` flag, e.g

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory=Default --disable-renderer-accessibility
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem related to accesibility in Chrome 89.

You can solve it including the following code in the CSS of your site or app. It will remove bootstrap transitions. I think this is a better fix than what was suggested in another answer if you are actually providing service to other people and you can't tell them to include a special parameter when they open their browser.

```css
select {

-webkit-transition: none !important;

-moz-transition: none !important;

-o-transition: none !important;

transition: none !important;

}

option {

-webkit-transition: none !important;

-moz-transition: none !important;

-o-transition: none !important;

transition: none !important;

}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't kniw about it. It will be fixed in v90 which is in beta now